# wpf: expecting Double.Nan - strange behavior of Frameworkelement Layout value

Tags: wpf, layout, autosize

I'm developing a wpf Expander Control derived from System.Windows.Controls.Expander, which provides, among other features, animation of collapsing / expanding.

```
var sbExpanding = new Storyboard();
var da = new DoubleAnimation { From = 0, To = expandHeight, Duration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 250)) };
Storyboard.SetTarget(da, Content as FrameworkElement);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, new PropertyPath("(FrameworkElement.Height)"));
sbExpanding.Children.Add(da);
this.BeginStoryboard(sbExpanding);
```

The Control should return to auto-size after animation is done:

```
sbExpanding.Completed += (sender, args) =>
{
     var cp = Content as FrameworkElement;
     if (cp != null)
     {
          // neither one of the following lines works
          cp.Height = double.NaN;
          cp.ClearValue(HeightProperty);
     }
};
```

After animating, the height is '38.3'. Calling

```
cp.Height = Double.NaN
```

or

```
cp.ClearValue(HeightProperty);
```

both sets the value to '38.96'.

The xaml for this test is pretty simple:

```
<ctrl:AnimatedExpander VerticalAlignment="Top" Header="ExpanderHeader" EnableAnimation="True">
    <Expander.Content>
        <Border>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="ExpanderContent" TextAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Expander.Content>
</ctrl:AnimatedExpander>
```

Why is it not set to NaN ? Why did the deafult change from Nan to a double ?
Before animating, the Height is NaN, which is I want to keep!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:
if uiElem is the UIElement to animate, call

```
uiElem .BeginAnimation(HeightProperty, null);
```

which passes a null-timeline and so kind of "releases" the dependency property!
Nice that it is documented in msdn:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970493%28v=vs.110%29.aspx